# Getting File and Folder List from Remote Server in PHP

Tags: php

When I run:

```
$url='foldername';
$dir = opendir($url);

//List files in images directory
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
  {

  echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";
  }
closedir($dir);
```

...it outputs:

```
filename: a.gif 
filename: file.html
filename: g.gif
filename: gg.html
```

I would like to see all the files and folders on another server from the URL:

```
$url="http ://example.com"
```

How do I find the files and folder names from `example.com`?

Comment: Do you really want to browse an url for all files and folders (impossible/see answers) or are you trying to list all files and files on your server/webspace?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible. Just got to go outside the box. Only flaw with this is index output

```
<?
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/(a href\=\")([^\?\"]*)(\")/i", get_text('http://www.website.com/ images/'), $matches);
    foreach($matches[2] as $match)
    {
        echo $match . '<br>';
    }

    function get_text($filename)
    {
        $fp_load = fopen("$filename", "rb");
        if ( $fp_load )
        {
            while ( !feof($fp_load) )
            {
                $content .= fgets($fp_load, 8192);
            }
            fclose($fp_load);
        return $content;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

`http://` does not support directory listing.  What you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: Then how to open that .. There was any function to open file

Comment: @vineeth:  Like I said, it's impossible to get the remote directory listing of an http server. Unless you have another route into the server, such as FTP access, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible of course, otherwise websites would be much more vulnerable since anyone could explore their directories tree!

If you have another way of accessing that website (e.g. if it's yours), like FTP or SSH, it becomes possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with php is impossible.. but there r programs that can do what u r trying to do.
"intellitamper" is one of them. http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/IntelliTamper.shtml <-- the link.

- its doesnt work on windows 7
- u cannot get server sides files like php.
- u can only see folders, html, js or image files.

Otherwise it would be heaven... anyone could hack any website.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine in some servers

```
function get_text($filename) {

    $fp_load = fopen("$filename", "rb");

    if ( $fp_load ) {

            while ( !feof($fp_load) ) {
                $content .= fgets($fp_load, 8192);
            }

            fclose($fp_load);

            return $content;

    }
}


$matches = array();

preg_match_all("/(a href\=\")([^\?\"]*)(\")/i", get_text('https://www.example.com/'), $matches);

foreach($matches[2] as $match) {
    echo $match . '<br>';
}
```